# Trait type and lifetime issues

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write an Iron plugin middleware, but I'm running into an issue when trying to define a `typemap` key:

The minimal example with simple type works without issues:

```rust
pub struct Database;
impl Key for Database {
    type Value = isize;
}
```

But as soon as lifetime is involved, I cannot compile the library:

```rust
pub struct Database<'a> {
    pool: &'a Arc<Pool<PostgresConnectionManager>>
}

impl<'a> Key for Database<'a> {
    type Value = PooledConnection<'a, PostgresConnectionManager>;
}
```

What's happening here? I get the errors:

```
src/lib.rs:33:1: 35:2 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 33:0...
src/lib.rs:33 impl<'a> Key for Database<'a> {
src/lib.rs:34     type Value = PooledConnection<'a, PostgresConnectionManager>;
src/lib.rs:35 }
src/lib.rs:33:1: 35:2 note: ...so that trait type parameters matches those specified on the impl (expected `typemap::Key`, found `typemap::Key`)
src/lib.rs:33 impl<'a> Key for Database<'a> {
src/lib.rs:34     type Value = PooledConnection<'a, PostgresConnectionManager>;
src/lib.rs:35 }
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
src/lib.rs:33:1: 35:2 note: ...so that the type `r2d2::PooledConnection<'_, r2d2_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
src/lib.rs:33 impl<'a> Key for Database<'a> {
src/lib.rs:34     type Value = PooledConnection<'a, PostgresConnectionManager>;
src/lib.rs:35 }
```

But that doesn't make sense to me - the `PooledConnection` cannot outlive the manager and the `Arc<Pool<...Manager>>` is given that lifetime to ensure this. What am I missing here?

([documentation for Pool](https://sfackler.github.io/r2d2/doc/r2d2/struct.Pool.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the definition of `Key`:

```
pub trait Key: Any {
    type Value: Any;
}
```

That is, it extends trait [`Any`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html):

```rust
pub trait Any: 'static + Reflect {
    fn get_type_id(&self) -> TypeId;
}
```

This means that any type which implements `Key` must also implement `Any`, and any `Value` associated type instantiation must also implement `Any`. However, `Any` is only defined for types which are `'static`, that is, which do not contain non-static references.

Types which are parameterized with lifetime parameters, like your `Database`, usually do contain such references (and indeed, your type contains `&'a` field), so they are not `'static` and so they cannot implement `Any`. Therefore such types can't implement `Key`. And this is in fact what your error is about, even if this is not really obvious:

```
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

Anyway, the core reason of this error is that Rust currently does not support reflection with `Any` for non-static types - as far as I remember, there were some kind of soundness issues around lifetimes here. So currently your only option is to refactor your program so you won't need to store non-`'static` types in `TypeMap`.